# Destination host unreachable when using ping<hostname> but no issue with ping <ipaddress>

Tags: networking, unix, dns, routing, ping

I have 6 VMs with CentOS called n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, lnx-app1 with the below IP addresses:

```
n1.xyz.com = 10.10.100.101
n2.xyz.com = 10.10.100.102
n3.xyz.com = 10.10.100.103
n4.xyz.com = 10.10.100.104
n5.xyz.com = 10.10.100.105
lnx-app1   = 10.10.100.31
```

When I login to `lnx-app1` and try to ping `n1` using IP Address, i.e.,
`ping 10.10.100.101` from lnx-app1, it's working fine.

But when I try to ping using hostname (i.e., `ping n1.xyz.com`), it shows

```
Destination Host Unreachable.
```

I checked some related questions but I couldn't find solution to this issue.

Comment: What host name service are you using?  `hosts` files?  DNS?  When you ping by name, does it say what IP address it is trying to ping?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Do you have in house DNS server? and have you added these machines in forward and reverse lookup. If is it so can you post the nslookup for any one or the above mentioned machines for further clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided information about your host hypervisor's networking configuration which is very important.

Quick solution is to add IPs and full hostnames to /etc/hosts file of each of your VMs.